# XSLT Multiple Input Values have a same tag and need to put a condition per line

Tags: xslt

**[ Problem ]**
I have input values that have the same tag names where I need to separate or put condition-specific per line. For example, when `<data>` starts with 5, it needs to output the values on a parent node then when the succeeding value of `<data>` starts with 6 it needs to output as a child of the first data. After the 2nd data when the next record starts with 5 it needs to create a new `<test>` tag.
***Note**: Values that don't start to '5' or '6' shouldn't be printed.

I have tried lot of condition and doesn't solve this. Please advise for the best solution. Thank you!

Current syntax execute data like this:

```
<test/>
<test>
 <data>51234</data>
 <test1>
  <data>61234</data>
 </test1>
 <test1>
  <data>67890</data>
 </test1>
</test>

<test>
 <data>56789</data>
 <test1>
  <data>61234</data>
 </test1>
 <test1>
  <data>67890</data>
 </test1>
</test>
```

**[ Current syntax ]**

```
<xsl:for-each select="test/data">
<test>
    <xsl:if test="starts-with(., '5')">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="../../test/data">
        <xsl:if test="starts-with(., '6')">
           <test1>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           <test1>
        </xsl:if>
<test>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**[ Input ]**

```
<test>
    <data>11234</data>                                              
</test>
<test>
    <data>51234</data>                                              
</test>
<test>
    <data>61234</data>
</test>
<test>
    <data>56789</data>                                             
</test>
<test>
    <data>67890</data>
</test>
```

**[ Expected Output ]**

```
<test>
  <data>51234</data> 
  <test1>
        <data>61234</data>
  </test1>
</test>
<test>
  <data>56789</data> 
  <test1>
        <data>67890</data>
  </test1>
</test>
```

Comment: The rules do not cover all possible scenarios. What if you have a sequence of 5xxx, 6xxx, 6yyy or 5xxx, 6xxx, 1xxx, 6yyy? Should 6yyy be nested under 5xxx?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sorry about that, but yes. 6yyyy will be nested below the 5xxx.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="test[matches(data, '^[56])]" 
    group-starting-with="data[matches(., '^5')]">
  <test>
    <data>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]/data"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[position() gt 1]">
       <test1>
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </test1>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </data>
  </test>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

This is XSLT 2.0. A 1.0 solution is much more difficult.

Comment: I have tried this but output displayed like this, which is not what I am expecting.

<test>
  <data>51234</data> 
  <test1>
        <data>61234</data>
  </test1>
  <test1>
        <data>56789</data>
  </test1>
  <test1>
        <data>67890</data>
  </test1>
</test>
<test>
  <data>56789</data> 
  <test1>
        <data>67890</data>
  </test1>
</test>

I think the main issue is that how will I be able to break the for-each loop when <data> starts with 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use XSL 2.0, then Dr. Kay's suggestion should work for you - with the following corrections/simplifications:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="test[matches(data, '^[56]')]" 
    group-starting-with="test[matches(data, '^5')]">
  <test>
      <xsl:copy-of select="data"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group() except .">
       <test1>
         <xsl:copy-of select="data"/>
       </test1>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </test>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B6H